How to set voltage of channel_1/ channel_2 of oscilloscope using yaml file(Oscilloscope is created using pyvisa and pyvisa-sim and yamal file)
I got the correct voltage, current and frequency reading But what parameters to set in yamal file for checking individual channel voltage/frequency and also other parameters of virtual oscilloscope using pyvisa-sim?
Here is referred yaml file:
spec: "1.0"
devices:
gpib_dev:
eom:
GPIB INSTR:
q: "\n"
r: "\n"
ASRL INSTR:
q: "\r\n"
r: "\n"
TCPIP INSTR:
q: "\n"
r: "\n"
USB INSTR:
q: "\n"
r: "\n"
error: ERROR from GPIB Instruments (Oscilloscope)
dialogues:
- q: "?IDN"
r: "GPIB DEVICE"
- q: "*CMD_F?"
r: "333000HZ"
- q: "MEAS:VOLT:DC?"
r: "10 Volts"
properties:
  current:
    default: 1.0
    getter:
      q: ":CURR:IMM:AMPL?"
      r: "{:+.8E}"
    setter:
      q: ":CURR:IMM:AMPL {:.3f}"
    specs:
      min: 1
      max: 6
      type: float  
  freq:
    default: 100.0e+09
    setter:
      q: "freq {:.2f}Hz"
    getter:
      q: "freq?"
      r: "{:.2f}"   
  voltage:
    default: 1.0
    getter:
      q: 'MEAS:VOLT:DC?'
      r: "{:+.2E}"
    setter:
      q: ":vol {:.3f}"
    specs:
      min: 1
      max: 6
      type: float                                                 

